# Ionic Angular: Children Do Not Get Rendered

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So this is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [RegisteredGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./tabs/tabs.module').then((m) => m.TabsPageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    canActivate: [RegisteredGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminPageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./account/login/login.module').then((m) => m.LoginPageModule),
  }
];
```

This is my structure:

[image: structure]

This is my `admin-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./account/manage-account/manage-account.module').then(
            (m) => m.ManageAccountPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/admin/account',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/admin/account',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

When I type `/admin/account` it should render the component from `/admin/account/manage-account`. The problem is that my `/admin/account/manage-account` is not being rendered.

The `/admin.page.html` is being rendered tho. So I guess the routing until `/admin` is correct, but the children of `/admin/...` routing do not get rendered.

Please help

---

### UPDATE

This is my `/admin/account/manage-account/manage-account-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ManageAccountPage,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ManageAccountPageRoutingModule {}
```

Also this is my `manage-account.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ManageAccountPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ManageAccountPage],
})
export class ManageAccountPageModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('HEREEEE');
  }
}
```

Weirdly enough, the `console.log('HEREEEE')` is working, it is getting called. But all the codes from `manage-account.page.ts` does not get ran at all.

Comment: Can you provide the routing module of `manage-account.module`?

Comment: Can you try changing all the `redirectTo` path in your  `admin-routing.module.ts`  to `redirectTo: '/admin/account'/manage-account`